# Show package explorer in PyDev Debug perspective

Tags: eclipse, pydev

How do I show the package explorer in PyDev debug view?

The way it is now, the package explorer disappears when the view switches. This then shifts the editor left; Super annoying.

I have tried window > show view > other > pydev >...

Answer (score 0):

There are some choices:

1. You can use `Alt+Shift+W` then select `PyDev Package explorer` (this will also select the file for the current editor in the `PyDev Package explorer`) -- this is the one I usually use as it's also useful to select the current file.
2. Use `Ctrl+3` then type `PyDev Package explorer` (you probably won't have to type it all, just a part of it).
3. Use the menu `Window > Show View > other > PyDev > PyDev Package Explorer`.